# Drupal 7 - How can I overwrite uploaded file via Filefield?

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

By default in Drupal 7, if I upload image.jpg via a file field in my node, save the node and then edit that same node and re-upload image.jpg, it will name it image_0.jpg.

I want to replace the image uploaded so I will only ever have image.jpg. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the original image is still stored in the file system (although not linked from the node anymore), so you should first remove the first image from the file server, not only the reference from the node.

I would do this using the user interface through admin > content > media.

Hope it helps.